# Text file to CSV conversion

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file which have content like :

```
Name: Aar saa
 Last Name: sh
 DOB: 1997-03-22
 Phone: 1212222
 Graduation: B.Tech
 Specialization: CSE
 Graduation Pass Out: 2019
 Graduation Percentage: 60
 Higher Secondary Percentage: 65
 Higher Secondary School Name: Guru Nanak Dev University,amritsar
 City: hyd
 Venue Details: CMR College of Engineering & Technology (CMRCET) Medchal Road, TS � 501401

Name: bfdg df
 Last Name: df
 DOB: 2005-12-16
 Phone: 2222222
 Graduation: B.Tech
 Specialization: EEE
 Graduation Pass Out: 2018
 Graduation Percentage: 45
 Higher Secondary Percentage: 45
 Higher Secondary School Name: asddasd
 City: vjd
 Venue Details: Prasad V. Potluri Siddhartha Institute Of Technology, Kanuru, AP - 520007

Name: cc dd ee
 Last Name: ee
 DOB: 1995-07-28
 Phone: 444444444
 Graduation: B.Tech
 Specialization: ECE
 Graduation Pass Out: 2019
 Graduation Percentage: 75
 Higher Secondary Percentage: 93
 Higher Secondary School Name: Sasi institute of technology and engineering
 City: hyd
 Venue Details: CMR College of Engineering & Technology (CMRCET) Medchal Road, TS � 501401
```

I want to convert it CSV file with headers as

['Name', 'Last Name','DOB', 'Phone', 'Graduation','Specialization','Graduation Pass Out','Higher Secondary School Name','City','Venue Details']

with value as all the value after ':'

I have done something like this:

```
writer = csv.writer(open('result.csv', 'a'))
writer.writerow(['Name', 'Last Name','DOB', 'Phone', 'Graduation','Specialization','Graduation Pass Out','Graduation Percentage','Higher Secondary Percentage','Higher Secondary School Name','City','Venue Details'])

with open('Name2.txt') as f:
        text = f.read()
        myarray = text.split("\n\n")
        for text1 in myarray:
            parselines(text1, writer)

def parselines(lines,writer):
    data=[]
    for line in lines.split('\n'):
        Name = line.split(": ",1)[1]
        data.append(Name)
    writer.writerow(data)
```

It worked but any efficient way would be much appreciated.

Comment: `I want to ...` is not a valid problem statement. What did you try? Where are you stuck? Where is your [mcve]?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I have added what i tried.

Comment: **`It worked`** `but any efficient way would be much appreciated.` => then this post is by definition off topic on Stackoverflow: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - btw. I find your solution clearer then the only proposed answer so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm works (kind-of a state machine)

1. If blank line, make a new row
2. Otherwise: add to current row, collect all headers and fields

```
def parselines(lines):
    header = []
    csvrows = [{}]
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
           csvrows.append({})  # new row, in dict form
        else:
           field, data = line.split(":", 1)
           csvrows[-1][field] = data
           if field not in header:
               header.append(field)
    # format CSV
    print(",".join(header))
    for row in csvrows:
        print(",".join(row.get(h,"") for h in header))
```

Comment: it is throwing an error saying "lstrip() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)"

Comment: @Rahul sorry, typo. I mean split(), not lstrip(). This is to split string by ":" for exactly once. Strip doesn't make sense there.